# How can I remove all text after the 2nd full-stop from all cells in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have the following excel spreadsheet above, except with 7500 more lines.

I want to remove the second `'.'` and all characters after it in each cell in my latitude and longitude columns.

I've tried google searching formulas to do this but I'm not sure how to apply them to each row, nor can I get them to work with full stops. I tried the following formula but it gives me the error "There was something wrong with your formula".

```
=IF(ISERR(LEFT(E1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E1,".",CHAR(1),2))-1)),E1,LEFT(E1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(E1,".",CHAR(1),2))-1))
```

Comment: Which language is your version of EXCEL. Perhaps replace `CHAR(1)` with `"+"` or something else. I recently had this problem.

Comment: I translated the formula to my language and it is working. Take care for the formatting of your lattitude and longitude cells. The need to be formatted as text.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, would you not just find the "." after the first one?
`=LEFT(E1,FIND(".",E1,FIND(".",E1)+1)-1)`

Comment: Most likely there is a translation problem. I will guess that your language uses a semicolon for the list separator, and possibly a dot for the digit separator.  The formula is US-centric where we use comma for the list and digit separator.  You'll need to properly translate the formula, and you may have to modify things if your values are numeric rather than being strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sample data is located in A1, do :

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1,1)+1)-1)
```

idea : use mid and recursive find .